# create reponsive div 16:9

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I was creating a 16:9 ratio responsive div , however when I resize the window the `container3` still stay with the original size , any problem in my code ? Anyone able to help me ? Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 rp_config();

});
$(window).resize(function(){
 rp_config();

});
function rp_config(){
 var windowwidth = $(window).width();
 var windowheight = $(window).height();
 var bar = 64;
 var bottom = 45;
 var chat = 250;
 var container2_width = windowwidth - chat;
 var available_height = windowheight - bar - bottom;
 
 $(".container").width(windowwidth);
 $(".container2").width(container2_width);
 $(".container3").width(available_height / 9 * 16);
 
 $(".container").height(available_height);
 $(".container2").height(available_height);
 $(".container3").height(available_height);
 
 

}
rp_config();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="background-color:#000;">
 <div class="container2" style="background-color:#333;">
     <div class="container3" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran your snippet, but it seems the container3 Do change its size relatively, can you further explain how it not changed, or what did you do, what you expect it to be, and the unexpected come out.

Comment: Why are you using javascript for simple layout task?

Comment: @fuyushimoya resizing window width , container3 will become smaller and with aspect ratio 16:9

Comment: @BogdanKuštan because the width and height must calculate from window width and window height, so i need javascript

Comment: Can't you simply use `vw` and `vh` units instead? :)

Comment: @ImHappy You must notice that the container3 only cares about window's height, so it'll detect the height it can use, and resize it self to 16:9, relative to window height, not window width.

Comment: @Terry how ? `container3` width and height must calculate from window width and window height

Comment: @fuyushimoya you have example to show me?

Comment: @ImHappy can't you use something like [padding hack](http://jsfiddle.net/cape87ah/) for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uv8wu7fb/ I've create 2 sets of your elements, and only alter to show what it comes out under different heights, as you can see, the container3 will stick 16:9 base on the given height. While width have no influence to container3.

Comment: @BogdanKuštan I already tell you I need calculate the size from window size , if I hardcode css how I know different computer screen size to resize?

Comment: @fuyushimoya still have the same problem that I mention, when I resize window width the `container3` still the same size, yeah it is 16:9 , but it not automatically resize to smaller or bigger when I resize the window width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide whether container3's width is larger than container2.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 rp_config();

});
$(window).resize(function(){
 rp_config();

});

function rp_config(){
  var windowwidth = $(window).width();
  var windowheight = $(window).height();
  var bar = 64;
  var bottom = 45;
  var chat = 250;
  var container2_width = windowwidth - chat;
  var available_height = windowheight - bar - bottom;
  

  var altWidth = available_height / 9 * 16
      ,altHeight = available_height;
  if (altWidth > container2_width) {
    altWidth = container2_width;
    altHeight = altWidth / 16 * 9;
  }   
  
  $(".container").width(windowwidth);
  $(".container2").width(container2_width);
  $(".container3").width(altWidth);
  
  $(".container").height(available_height);
  $(".container2").height(available_height);
  $(".container3").height(altHeight);
}
rp_config();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='case1' class="container" style="background-color:#000;">
 <div class="container2" style="background-color:#333;">
     <div class="container3" style="background-color:#ccc;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here I use altHeight to keep container3 to keep a 16:9 ratio, you can remove it if you want it to fill up whole container2 area.

Comment: thanks you so much ~~ this confuse my 2 hours now only left to set the `container3` to middle using css left , I can make my own ... again thanks you ~

Comment: Glad to keep you happy :D